# Fragment's LinearLayout replaceing a ScrollView doesn't match the height of its parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I have a drawer layout in which a scroll view is located. Both have `layout_height="match_parent"`.

I commit a fragment transaction that replaces the scroll view by a linear layout (`fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.scrollView, fragment_seals);` ).

This linear layout also has `layout_height="match_parent"`.
However, the linear layout's height doesn't match its parent's height (the drawer layout, since it replaces the scroll view which is the child of the drawer layout). Do you know why?

The drawer layout is the root.

The drawer layout correctly matches its "parent" (the viewport / screen of the device), I checked it out. But the linear layout just wraps its own content, I'm sure at 100%.

## Sources

### The linear layout of the fragment that replaces the scroll view

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/seals_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorRichYellow"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/choose_seal" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/handle_publication_share_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### The layout of the activity that makes the commit of the fragment transition, replacing its scroll view by the linear layout

```
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- Container for contents of drawer - use NavigationView to make configuration easier -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/color_states_menu"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_share"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_share_black_18dp"
            android:background="@color/colorRoyalRedLight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraint_layout_bottom"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

### The fragment transition

```
public class ActivityHandlingFragments extends AppCompatActivity {

    // <!------------------------------------------ BEGINNING - Defining fragments instances -->
    SealsFragment fragment_seals = new SealsFragment();
    // <!------------------------------------------ END - Defining fragments instances -->

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_handling_fragments);

        final FragmentManager fragment_manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragment_transaction = fragment_manager.beginTransaction();  // When app starts
        fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.scrollView, fragment_home);
        fragment_transaction.commit();

        NavigationView navigation_view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigation_view.getMenu().getItem(0).setCheckable(true);
        navigation_view.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

        final DrawerLayout drawer_layout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                item.setChecked(true);
                drawer_layout.closeDrawers();

                // <!-------------------------------------- BEGINNING - NavigationView's routing -->
                FragmentTransaction fragment_transaction = fragment_manager.beginTransaction();
                switch(item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.menu_item_home_page:
                    case R.id.menu_item_my_seals:
                        fragment_transaction.replace(R.id.scrollView, fragment_seals);
                        break;
                }
                fragment_transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragment_transaction.commit();
                // <!-------------------------------------------- END - NavigationView's routing -->

                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Your `FragmentTransaction` does not replace the `ScrollView`. A `replace()` transaction just removes a `Fragment` that might already be in the `ViewGroup` you pass it. The `ViewGroup` is still always there, so your `Fragment` is just being added inside the `ScrollView`. Are you correctly inflating the layout in your `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method, passing the `ViewGroup` parameter as the parent in the `inflate()` call?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, even if you are passing the parent in `inflate()` correctly, the `ScrollView` might still be forcing a wrap on the height. You could add `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `<ScrollView>` tag, or possibly change the container `ViewGroup` to something other than `ScrollView`, depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish there.

Comment: But the `ScrollView` matches the parent, right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're getting at, but yes. Any non-drawer `View` in a `DrawerLayout` is always laid out to `match_parent` in both directions.

Comment: Then as you said, the linear layout of my fragment is added inside the scroll view which maps the drawer layout which maps the screen of the device. But the linear layout matches its parent, in other terms it matches the scroll view. Then why doesn't it matches the screen of the device?

Comment: Please refer to [my second comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54172754/fragments-linearlayout-replaceing-a-scrollview-doesnt-match-the-height-of-its?noredirect=1#comment95174784_54172754).

Comment: Mmmh note sure to have well understood 1) why it works using `fillViewport` to true, since the `ScrollView` is censed to already matches - finally - the viewport, 2) your second comment. But it works yes. Do you know if it could have other consequencies than fixing this problem? In particular, negative consequencies

Comment: Well, using a `ScrollView` as a `Fragment` container might cause you some unexpected behavior down the line, but `fillViewport` itself won't cause any issues. It just makes it lay out its child to fill, if it doesn't happen to be already as big or bigger than the `ScrollView` itself.

Comment: You should, if you want, answer this question in order to make me able to close it.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. :-) It was just a quick suggestion. Nothing major. Please feel free to post an answer yourself, if you like, or to delete this, if you'd rather. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad I could help. Cheers!